# Can Circuit Value Problem or HORN-SAT be reduced to PATH problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, satisfiability

PATH = {(X,R,S,T) | exists an x in S that is admissible}
Where R is a relation of X x X x X, S is a unary relation of X and T is a unary relation of X aswell.
An x element of X is admissible if it is in T or if there is two elements y z both admissibles, where (x,y,z) is in R.

So, is there any logspace reduction from CVP or HORN-SAT to this problem, so I can prove that PATH is P-Complete?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I already know that PATH is p-complete, I need to prove it.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We are not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: I tried to reduce CVP, relating the input of CVP with T and the output with S. Relating R with the 2 inputs in a logic door and the output. Here is where I got stuck. I need to relate the negations doors (no clue here yet) and to prove that this reduction will do, I have been trying to get to the answer for days. Im not trying to skip homework, I just dont know how to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Reduce from the monotone circuit value problem. Let $X$ be the set of all inputs and internal gates in the circuit. Choose $T$ and $R$ so that an element is admissible if the corresponding input or gate is *true* (each AND gate will require one triple in $R$, each OR gate will require two). Choose $S$ to be the indicator of the output gate to complete the proof.

Comment: I understand that the AND gate will require one, but why the OR gate will require two?

Comment: If you can do it with one, great. Otherwise you will need two. Now I suggest that you take a few hours to solve the problem on your own, and only if you get stuck, ask more questions here.